# Access only save record update on button click

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a table in Access.  I would like to create a form that would allow a user to review each record in the table, update a single column called "GoodMatch" with a 1 or 0 and then commit the edits to the table.  I would like for the user to be able to view multiple records at a time.  I have figured out how to view multiple records by setting the data sheet view to be the default view.  The column is editable, but it seems to saving the values to the table on entry as opposed to when a button is clicked to save the record.  How do I get it to only save upon click a button?  I am not very experience with VBA, so if there is a non VBA method that would be preferable. Thanks!

Comment: You need VBA. To make it work you'd need to make the controls unbound.

Answer (score 3):

This is default behavior of bound forms and it cannot be changed. As a workaround you can use for editing one record unbound controls. If you need to edit few records and save changes only after clicking Save button, copy edited data to temporary table, allow user edit it, by pressing Save button validate all data and copy data back to working table if the data valid. You can reset temporary table for undo all changes. Unfortunately this cannot be done without using VBA or macro, just few rows for running query, which copies data to temporary table at edit start and run query, which updates work table for saving changes, it's easy.